# Xbox 360 game sound through headset

Tags: xbox-360, controllers, audio-hardware

I recently purchased a converter so that I could hook up my PC headset to my Xbox 360 controller. However, when I try to use it, no sound comes through the headset.

I do not have Xbox Live gold, and I do not need to listen to the voices of other people, nor do I need to play my voice through the headset. I do, however, want to be able to play my Xbox on my computer monitor, which has no speakers attached.

I can hook up video to the monitor with a HDMI cable, but I can't hear the sound through the headset. Is the converter broken, do I have a setting wrong, or is it just not something I can do? Is there a way for me to connect the headset directly to the Xbox 360?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade. Could you tell us what converter you are using?

Answer (score 2):

So, you require an Xbox stereo connector. It is a $15 cable to connect sound to external stereo(or headphones with RCA or a 3.5mm headphone to RCA converter($2)).
The question has been answered before in the question "connecting an xbox 360 to a computer screen. I will look for the link for you, though figured you want an answer sooner than later.

Comment: Having a lot of trouble finding that post. Shall keep on it, but hopefully someone will post the link.

Comment: Using Pc as speakers for Xbox 360 is the best I could find.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is likely because the Xbox 360 controller microphone is only used for online chat. Because of this, [it appears the console does not send it regular sound.](http://www.xboxachievements.com/forum/showthread.php?t=297216) If you connect both the RCA and HDMI at the same time, however, you should be able to use the HDMI for your monitor, and use the RCA audio to connect to your headset.

---

#### Connecting HDMI and RCA at the same time

AFAIK, the Xbox 360 RCA plug blocks off HDMI, but if you really want to get it connected and feel confident enough, [there is a good guide to modify the RCA plug to accommodate the HDMI](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-To-Xbox360-HDMI-RCA-audio/?ALLSTEPS). You basically use a thin flat-head screwdriver to pop open the plastic surrounding the plug connector, and remove the side facing the HDMI, before insulating it with electrical tape.

---

#### Connecting the headset

Without knowing the adapter you are using, specifically, we can at least assume that you are at the stage where the headset is working with the standard Xbox 360 audio port, 2.5mm.

What you need is a 2.5mm female to 2 RCA female adapter. It might be easier to use a 2.5mm to 3.5mm adapter, and a 3.3mm female to 2 RCA female adapter, as 3.5mm can be a lot more common. If you do not know what any of this is, go into your local electric wholesaler. Places like ebay offer a cheap alternative, too.

[image][image]

---

**Just connect everything up, and you should get sound through your headset, and video through your monitor.**